# How to set :hover as default and reset once moused over?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am currently working on a website that has two columns of square images. Each column has 3 images, so 6 images total. Each image has a hover state with text and a 'learn more' link.

The intent is that users hover over each image to learn more about the client's company. To help facilitate users hovering over the images, I am trying to force the first image to have it's hover state as the default view. If you mouse over it, once your mouse leaves, it resets to just the plain image, and resumes normal hover functionality.

If possible, what is the best way to accomplish this effect?

Comment: Sounds like you need to set up event handlers in javascript or jquery to change your images on hover. The native [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) function or jquery's [hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) methods could be used to listen for the hover and execute a callback function, which contains the logic that would swap out your image for something else.

Comment: You also might be able to avoid using JS completely and go with a pure css solution. [This example](http://jsfiddle.net/akirchmyer/x71av6jd/) is a work in progress but may be a step in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's OK to use jQuery, keep reading.

Instead of having the pseudo class `:hover` on the first item, you can give it a real class such as `.active`, either in the markup or through jQuery, and make the style exactly the same as `:hover`. Then remove the that class when it was hovered once.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/96mwjs0x/1/

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>11111</li>
    <li>22222</li>
    <li>33333</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
li:hover,
li.active {
    color: red;
}
```

jQuery

```
$(function() {
    $("li:first-child").addClass("active")
    $(".active").mouseover(function() {
      $(this).removeClass("active");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, you can do this by using event handlers:

```
$(".square").hover(function(){
    $(this).addClass("hover");
}, function(){
    $(this).removeClass("hover");
})
```

have your first picture initialized with "hover" class and don't use native css :hover pseudo class

https://jsfiddle.net/pa8frf89/